# USB HDDs are failing with xHCI error. Requiring restart

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive

I have 2 hard drives connected with SATA-to-USB tool. Usually they work fine however some time to time they fail and they don't show up on Disks neither I can see the connection on dmesg. dmesg output on connection then later failure.

```
[  879.083720] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  879.247885] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  879.267450] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0539
[  879.267459] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=11, SerialNumber=3
[  879.267464] usb 2-1: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI bridge
[  879.267469] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: JMicron
[  879.267473] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 00A123456789
[  879.268565] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  879.269478] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: Quirks match for vid 152d pid 0539: 4000000
[  879.269525] scsi host7: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[  880.268102] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JMicron                   0000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
[  880.268507] scsi 7:0:0:1: Direct-Access     JMicron                   0000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
[  880.269396] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  880.269609] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
[  880.270140] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[  880.270151] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
[  880.270427] sd 7:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  880.270839] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[  880.270865] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  880.271124] sd 7:0:0:1: [sdd] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
[  880.273358] sd 7:0:0:1: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[  880.273371] sd 7:0:0:1: [sdd] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
[  880.274124] sd 7:0:0:1: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
[  880.274137] sd 7:0:0:1: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  880.297883]  sdc: sdc1
[  880.337211] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[  880.427270]  sdd: sdd1 sdd2
[  880.434783] sd 7:0:0:1: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
[  881.939128] systemd-hostnamed[5342]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[  889.090534] xhci_hcd 0000:0b:00.0: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command.
[  889.090546] xhci_hcd 0000:0b:00.0: Assuming host is dying, halting host.
[  889.143511] xhci_hcd 0000:0b:00.0: Host not halted after 16000 microseconds.
[  889.143520] xhci_hcd 0000:0b:00.0: Non-responsive xHCI host is not halting.
[  889.143525] xhci_hcd 0000:0b:00.0: Completing active URBs anyway.
[  889.143547] xhci_hcd 0000:0b:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
[  905.666192] xhci_hcd 0000:0b:00.0: Stopped the command ring failed, maybe the host is dead
[  905.719071] xhci_hcd 0000:0b:00.0: Host not halted after 16000 microseconds.
[  905.719079] xhci_hcd 0000:0b:00.0: Abort command ring failed
[  905.719085] xhci_hcd 0000:0b:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
[  905.719233] sched: RT throttling activated
[  905.719288] usb usb1-port1: couldn't allocate usb_device
[  905.719963] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
```

Even if I replug or turn off/on the device, dmesg doesn't change. I can't mount the drivers until restart.

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit

Kernel: 3.19.0-31-generic